# Чем воспользоваться для хранения такой очереди? Python

Tags: python

Программа получает на вход последовательность из N чисел. У нас имеется некоторое хранилище, куда можно положить только 5 чисел. Первые 5 чисел последовательности попадают в хранилище моментально. Последующие числа обрабатываются следующим образом:

1. Если число уже есть в хранилище, то все числа в хранилище сдвигаются и это число встает на последнюю позицию. Пример: [1, 4, 8, 2, 5] + 4 -> [1, 8, 2, 5, 4]
2. Если числа еще нет в хранилище, то удаляется число из начала хранилища, а добавляемое встает в конец.
   Пример: [1, 4, 8, 2, 5] + 9 -> [4, 8, 2, 5, 9]

Как реализовать такую структуру наиболее оптимально?
Пока я написал код только с использованием `deque`

```
def update(queue, number):
    if number in queue:
        queue.remove(number)
        queue.append(number)
    else:
        queue.popleft()
        queue.append(number)
```

Comment: числа в хранилище уникальны? если нет, что делать, если в хранилище два одинаковых числа?

Comment: Числа в хранилище уникальны. Уникальность первых пяти чисел гарантируется.

Comment: ну встроенную быструю структуру для хранения вам вряд ли предложат, разве сто deque из модуля collection так как он более быстрый с методами pop, чем обычный питоновский список. но с deque пробема выдергивать числа из середины. так что, в принципе, ваш подход правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, сделать так:

```
q = [1, 4, 8, 2, 5]

def updateq(q, num):
     return [x for x in q[not num in q:] if x!=num] + [num]

print(updateq(q, 4))
print(updateq(q, 9))
```

Результаты, соответственно:

```
[1, 8, 2, 5, 4]
[4, 8, 2, 5, 9]
```